# Error while trying to run 'npm start'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, package.json, npm-start

I am getting the below error while trying to run `npm start` without updating  the node version nor the npm version.

ERROR

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Work\node-v6.10.3-win-x64\node-v6.10.3-win-x64\node.exe" "
>   C:\Work\node-v6.10.3-win-x64\node-v6.10.3-win-x64\node_modules\npm\bin\np
>   m-cli.js" "start"
>   npm ERR! node v6.10.3
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! ucps-online-client@1.0.0 start: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.jso
>   n`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the ucps-online-client@1.0.0 start script 'ng serve --proxy-c
>   onfig proxy.conf.json'.
>   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ucps-online-client pa
>   ckage,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
>   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   npm ERR!     npm bugs ucps-online-client
>   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls ucps-online-client
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Work\workspace_Nov9_commit\ucps-online-parent\ucps-online-client
>   \npm-debug.log

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "ucps-online-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.6.3",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "latest-version": "^3.1.0",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.6.3",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^1.8.3",
    "ng2-datetime-picker": "^0.12.5",
    "ng2-pagination": "^2.0.2",
    "primeng": "4.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "^2.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.9.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you paste your package.json ? have you installed the packages required ?

Comment: Hi, I have added the package.json in question section

Comment: Can you also post your _proxy.conf.json_?

Comment: proxy.conf.json:{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}